# Replacing SQL Data Table with New Data

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have the following code, which uploads data from access to a SQL Server table. The problem is it wont overwrite/replace the table when I try to update it. I get an error saying the table already exists. I need to either add some code to delete the table so the new one can be uploaded or a way to append the new/edited records to the table.

```
Public Function Update()
DoCmd.TransferDatabase _
        acExport, _
        "ODBC Database", _
        "ODBC;" & _
            "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" & _
            "Server=SERVER;" & _
            "Database=DB;" & _
            "UID=ID;" & _
            "PWD=PW;", _
        acTable, _
        "CDData", _
        "AC_CDData", _
        False
End Function
```

So the AC_CDData table is the one that needs to be replaced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to DROP the existing destination table before transferring the new one then the code would be more like this:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function TransferTableToSqlServer()
    Dim cdb As dao.Database, qdf As dao.QueryDef
    Dim err As dao.Error
    Const DestinationTableName = "AC_CDData"
    Const ConnectionString = _
            "ODBC;" & _
                "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" & _
                "Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
                "Database=YourDatabaseName;" & _
                "UID=YourSqlUserId;" & _
                "PWD=YourSqlPassword;"
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")
    qdf.Connect = ConnectionString
    qdf.sql = _
            "IF EXISTS " & _
                "(" & _
                    "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES " & _
                    "WHERE TABLE_NAME='" & DestinationTableName & " '" & _
                ") " & _
            "DROP TABLE [" & DestinationTableName & "]"
    qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
    On Error GoTo TransferTableToSqlServer_qdfError
    qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase _
            acExport, _
            "ODBC Database", _
            ConnectionString, _
            acTable, _
            "CDData", _
            DestinationTableName, _
            False
    Exit Function

TransferTableToSqlServer_qdfError:
    For Each err In dao.Errors
        MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical, "Error " & err.Number
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: I  am getting an ODBC Call Error and it highlights QDF.EXECUTE dbFailOnError

Comment: @user2119980 Does the SQL user have sufficient permissions to DROP the table?

Comment: Normally I just have to hit delete and then verify. And the login information is administrator login credentials

Comment: @user2119980 Try the `IF EXISTS ... DROP TABLE` query in SQL Server Management Studio and see if it works there. I tested that VBA code against SQL Server 2008 R2 before posting my answer and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @user2119980 What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48726/discussion-between-user2119980-and-gord-thompson)

Comment: can you rejoin our chat?

Comment: The error message is now displaying: An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Add a name or single space as the alias name.