# ODBC Call Failed when linking two queries, but only on Outer Joins

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, inner-join

I have two queries, which use tables linked from an ODBC database, both are simple enough and indiviudally work fine.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT ExtraField.FieldName
FROM (ExtraField INNER JOIN ExtraFieldScope ON ExtraField.ExtraFieldID = ExtraFieldScope.ExtraFieldID) INNER JOIN ExtraGroup ON ExtraFieldScope.ExtraGroupID = ExtraGroup.ExtraGroupID
WHERE (((ExtraGroup.GroupDescription)="Client"))
ORDER BY ExtraField.FieldName;
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT ExtraField.FieldName
FROM (ExtraField INNER JOIN ExtraFieldScope ON ExtraField.ExtraFieldID = ExtraFieldScope.ExtraFieldID) INNER JOIN ExtraGroup ON ExtraFieldScope.ExtraGroupID = ExtraGroup.ExtraGroupID
WHERE (((ExtraGroup.GroupDescription)="Contact"))
ORDER BY ExtraField.FieldName;
```

I then tried to join the two queries with a left join, a la:

```
SELECT [Extra Fields - Client (Part 1)].FieldName AS [Client Field Name]
FROM [Extra Fields - Client (Part 1)] LEFT JOIN [Extra Fields - Client (Part 2)] ON [Extra Fields - Client (Part 1)].FieldName = [Extra Fields - Client (Part 2)].FieldName;
```

but that query throws up an "ODBC - Call Failed" error. However, this is only when I use an outer (LEFT) join. The following query works fine (but isn't what I want):

```
SELECT [Extra Fields - Client (Part 1)].FieldName AS [Client Field Name]
FROM [Extra Fields - Client (Part 1)] INNER JOIN [Extra Fields - Client (Part 2)] ON [Extra Fields - Client (Part 1)].FieldName = [Extra Fields - Client (Part 2)].FieldName;
```

What gives?

Comment: Run the query in VBA, trap the error with `On Error ...`, and then loop through the `DAO.Errors` collection to get more information on the underlying problem. (See my recent answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22105935/2144390) for an example of the error-trapping code.) What, if anything, do the additional error messages say?

Comment: I'm afraid that just throws up the same error three times?

Comment: I was able to recreate your issue. The error message I receive is quite lengthy and says things like 'The multi-part identifier "MS1.GroupDescription" could not be bound. (#4104)'. Since the underlying tables are ODBC linked tables can you create views on the server and then create an Access linked table to retrieve the results of the final view?

Comment: Thanks - yes, I think I'm going to have to look at this another way, seems to be a bug in Access from other Googling.

Comment: re: "bug in Access" - I'm not so sure about that. Another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14656582/2144390) suggests that the "multi-part identifier" error can occur in SQL Server itself, although Access' additional "meddling" in the process certainly could contribute to the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is LEFT JOIN causing a "multi-part identifier can't be bound" error when INNER JOIN does not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550925/why-is-left-join-causing-a-multi-part-identifier-cant-be-bound-error-when-inn)